# Why is my facebook app giving "'root' is null or not an object all.js"?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I created [this app](http://apps.facebook.com/estados/) with MVC3 and SDK. It loads the index page fine. When I click any link in the `iframe` fb app in Internet Explorer, it returns

> "root" is null or not an object all.js

and the app stops working. Why?

Comment: I don't open facebook links, but if there's no code at that site, you'll probably need to post some here if you want anyone to help you.